# String masking: Confoming text to a given mask

Tags: perl

Given the following text and mask string: -

```
text: the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
mask: xx xxx xxxx x xxx
```

I'm trying to find a terse way to arrive at the result: -

```
th qui brow f jum
```

The mask conforms the text to it's pattern. The resulting string should have the same amount of words as the mask.

My current implentation is using `List::Zip` to zip the words of each list together and do a string substitution. ( I've copied the logic of the zip function into the below example so you don't need to install it to test)

```
# Squashed version of List::Zip->zip function
sub zip{map{[map{shift@{$_}}@_]}0..((sort map{0+@{$_}}@_)[0]-1)}

my $mask = 'xx xxx xxxx x xxx';
my $text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

for my $mt ( zip( [split(' ', $mask)], [split(' ', $text)] ) ) {
    my ( $m, $t ) = @{ $mt };
    $mask =~ s/ $m / substr( $t, 0, length($m) ) /xe;
}

print $mask; # OUTPUT: th qui brow f jum
```

... but I can't help but think there's a shorter way. Maybe a funky regex trick?

Suggestions welcome.

**Update**

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1871197/3124587) is intriguing for it's use of `pos`. Trying to figure out how to apply it to my problem. (Edit: Borodin pointed out why it's not applicable to this problem)

I should also note that arbitrary whitespace is of no concern, ie given:

```
text: 'one    two three'
mask: 'x xx    xxx'
```

I don't care if the result that comes back is `o tw thr`. The only requirement is the same number of words, and the same length words.

**Review**

In the end I've accepted Alexandr's 'funky regex' solution. It's terse, and very fast, running the fastest Benchmarks by a comfortable margin.

Borodin's first solution, while very similar, created a regex pattern that didn't perform as well.

```
Borodin: (\S{1,2}) \S*\s+ (\S{1,3}) \S*\s+ (\S{1,4}) \S*\s+ (\S{1,1}) \S*\s+ (\S{1,3})
Alexandr: (\S{2})\S*\s+(\S{3})\S*\s+(\S{4})\S*\s+(\S{1})\S*\s+(\S{3})\S*
```

A few minor changes to Borodin's solution brings it on par with Alexandr's, but I gave it to Alexandr for arriving there first.

All the solutions are full of great and interesting idea's, thanks everyone.

Comment: Does your 'mask' have to be `x` ? because doing it as `.` (regex) would make it easier.

Comment: A space in the mask mean that we skip to the next word of the text, right?

Comment: Sobrique: It doesn't matter, `x` can always be converted to `.` easily with `s/x/./g`. simbabque: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Joshua: Is it possible that the mask may contain two spaces with no intervening `x`, signifying that a word of text should be skipped altogether, or is it words at the end of the mask that can be skipped? Is is possible that the text string may contain multiple spaces (or tabs?) which need to be retained in the result?

Comment: Hi Borodin, see my update... Arbitrary whites pace is irrelevant, there's no need to conform to the masks spacing. All remaining text is skipped.

Comment: The solution that you refer to isn't applicable in your case because it relies on the character positions in the text and mask strings matching one-for-one. You want to support multiple spaces between substrings, and the substrings themselves are probably shorter than the corresponding word in the text, which means the character position of an `x` in the mask is of no help in determining which character in the text should be included.

Comment: Thanks Borodin. I've not used the `pos` operator before so it was an interesting find for me, but I see why that answer can't apply to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean regex solution, transforming mask to the regex:

```
use strict;
use v5.10;

my $text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
my $mask = 'xx xxx xxxx x xxx';
say $mask;
$mask =~ s/(x+)/ '(\S{'.(length $1).'})\S*'/ge;
$mask =~ s/\s+/\\s+/g;
say $mask;
say join ' ', ($text =~ /^$mask/);
```

Comment: This builds a regex pretty much identical to my own regex solution, except that I allow a mask to be longer than the corresponding word in the text, resulting in the whole word being selected. The option of using substitutions instead of my `map` is interesting, though

Comment: This is a really clever and fast solution, Alexandr. Great work!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a word by word regex match, translating `x` to `.`.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
my $mask = 'xx xxx xxxx x xxx';

#split mask on whitespace
my @match = split ' ', $mask; 
print Dumper \@match;

#iterate each word in $text
foreach my $word ( split ' ', $text ) {
    #if no more 'match' entries, end. 
    last unless @match;

    #grab 'first' match pattern. and turn `xx` into `..`
    #e.g. a regex matching any 2 characters. 
    my $pattern = (shift @match) =~ s/x/./rg; 
    #trim words to match pattern
    print $word =~ s/^($pattern).*/$1/r, " ";
}
```

(note - `r` regex flag is a more recent feature. If it doesn't work in your version of perl, then you can instead `s/x/./g for @match` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways

Firstly, transforming the `$mask` value into a regular expression gives the correct result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
my $mask = 'xx xxx xxxx x xxx';

my $re = join ' \S*\s+ ', map { sprintf '(\S{1,%d})', length } split ' ', $mask;
$re = qr/$re/xs;

my $new = join ' ', $text =~ $re;

say $new;
```

Secondly, this transforms `$mask` into a list of substring lengths and uses it to convert the `$text` string

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
my $mask = 'xx xxx xxxx x xxx';

my @mask = map length, split ' ', $mask;

my $i = 0;
my $new = join ' ', map { $i > $#mask ? () : substr($_, 0, $mask[$i++]) } split ' ', $text;

say $new;
```

Finally, here's a neater rewrite of the second solution above with makes use of the `pairwise` function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::MoreUtils 'pairwise';

my $text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
my $mask = 'xx xxx xxxx x xxx';

my @text = split ' ', $text;
my @mask = split ' ', $mask;

my $new =  join ' ', pairwise { $b ? substr($a, 0, length $b) : () } @text, @mask;

say $new;
```